# How to change bootstrap modal-body Height after open it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### How to change model popup Height after open it using jQuery ?

My Button is

```
<button type="button" onclick="popUpSize();" 
     class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="#myModal">
         Launch demo modal
</button>
```

My jQuery Code is

```
function popUpSize(){
  var winHeight = $( window ).height();
  var popHeight = winHeight - 200;
  $('#myModal .modal-body').css('height', 'popHeight');
};
```

Comment: `popHeight` should not have quotes around it :)

Comment: why not add the height to css? use `vh`

Answer (score 2):

`popHeight` is a variable not a string, it shouldn't have quotes. Also you call this function on `shown.bs.modal` callback. You can use following code for this

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  popUpSize();
})

function popUpSize(){
  var winHeight = $( window ).height();
  var popHeight = winHeight - 200;
  $('#myModal .modal-body').css('height', popHeight);
};


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
```

Comment: can i use only it without onClick function :

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
  var winHeight = $( window ).height();
  var popHeight = winHeight - 200;
  $('#myModal .modal-body').css('height', popHeight);
  //popUpSize();
})

Comment: Yes you can use it without `onclick` function, check updated answer

Comment: @user1727852 if my answer solve your problem then please accept it.